Uninstalled python and lost my graphic interphase
I uninstalled python cause I installed an upgraded version python 3.12.2 and I felt it won't affect the system files but now I lost the graphic interphase, will I loose my files in trying to recover Ubuntu?

Does this answer your question? How to remove all traces of python from Ubuntu

Also see Upgrade python without breaking major applications

Does this answer your question? Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work
